# "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted"

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, remix

**Hello I am trying to deploy a contract using remix.ethereum.org after linked the metamask account using mumbai network.**

I receive this error while making the transaction for the contract

> Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The
> transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
> Internal JSON-RPC error. { **"code": -32000, "message": "execution
> reverted"** }

status  ***false Transaction mined but execution failed***
transaction hash    0x7af5f103024420440aa8c2314bd4a136fa3ce20b2cad325c662205308bb96f19
gas 3000000 gas
transaction cost    677934 gas
hash    0x7af5f103024420440aa8c2314bd4a136fa3ce20b2cad325c662205308bb96f19

```
[
    {
        "from": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010",
        "data": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000605718620be0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006d23f73843bdd2a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000812986dea162255c6d300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006cc3a01fe1b1f2a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008129873ef87a87684d3",
        "topics": [
            "0x4dfe1bbbcf077ddc3e01291eea2d5c70c2b422b415d95645b9adcfd678cb1d63",
            "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010",
            "0x0000000000000000000000002af41d8052ad1dfe56af7ce01beb8918985c94e3",
            "0x000000000000000000000000be188d6641e8b680743a4815dfa0f6208038960f"
        ]
    }
]
```

val 0 wei

Anyone has any idea how to solve it ?

That's the contract :

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Appoles is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
    using Strings for uint256;

    string public baseURI;
    string public baseExtension = ".json";
    uint256 public cost = 0.004 ether;
    uint256 public presaleCost = 0.004 ether;
    uint256 public maxSupply = 10;
    uint256 public maxMintAmount = 2;
    bool public paused = false;
    mapping(address => bool) public whitelisted;
    mapping(address => bool) public presaleWallets;

    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        string memory _initBaseURI
    ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
        setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
        mint(msg.sender, 20);
    }

    // internal
    function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return baseURI;
    }

    // public
    function mint(address _to, uint256 _mintAmount) public payable {
        uint256 supply = totalSupply();
        require(!paused);
        require(_mintAmount > 0);
        require(_mintAmount <= maxMintAmount);
        require(supply + _mintAmount <= maxSupply);

        if (msg.sender != owner()) {
            if (whitelisted[msg.sender] != true) {
                if (presaleWallets[msg.sender] != true) {
                    //general public
                    require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount);
                } else {
                    //presale
                    require(msg.value >= presaleCost * _mintAmount);
                }
            }
        }

        for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++) {
            _safeMint(_to, supply + i);
        }
    }

    function walletOfOwner(address _owner)
        public
        view
        returns (uint256[] memory)
    {
        uint256 ownerTokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);
        uint256[] memory tokenIds = new uint256[](ownerTokenCount);
        for (uint256 i; i < ownerTokenCount; i++) {
            tokenIds[i] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(_owner, i);
        }
        return tokenIds;
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        virtual
        override
        returns (string memory)
    {
        require(
            _exists(tokenId),
            "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token"
        );

        string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
        return
            bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0
                ? string(
                    abi.encodePacked(
                        currentBaseURI,
                        tokenId.toString(),
                        baseExtension
                    )
                )
                : "";
    }

    //only owner
    function setCost(uint256 _newCost) public onlyOwner {
        cost = _newCost;
    }

    function setPresaleCost(uint256 _newCost) public onlyOwner {
        presaleCost = _newCost;
    }

    function setmaxMintAmount(uint256 _newmaxMintAmount) public onlyOwner {
        maxMintAmount = _newmaxMintAmount;
    }

    function setBaseURI(string memory _newBaseURI) public onlyOwner {
        baseURI = _newBaseURI;
    }

    function setBaseExtension(string memory _newBaseExtension)
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        baseExtension = _newBaseExtension;
    }

    function pause(bool _state) public onlyOwner {
        paused = _state;
    }

    function whitelistUser(address _user) public onlyOwner {
        whitelisted[_user] = true;
    }

    function removeWhitelistUser(address _user) public onlyOwner {
        whitelisted[_user] = false;
    }

    function addPresaleUser(address _user) public onlyOwner {
        presaleWallets[_user] = true;
    }

    function add100PresaleUsers(address[100] memory _users) public onlyOwner {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            presaleWallets[_users[i]] = true;
        }
    }

    function removePresaleUser(address _user) public onlyOwner {
        presaleWallets[_user] = false;
    }

    function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
        (bool success, ) = payable(msg.sender).call{
            value: address(this).balance
        }("");
        require(success);
    }
}
```

Comment: I left the wei value to 0 and this happens when i deploy the contract

Comment: Could the problem be from the constructor  ?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the "Site Suggested" button on MetaMask transaction window and choose one of the options (Low, Market and Aggressive):

[image]